# VBA applied to complete workbook rather than sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code to create Timings but i can only use it on one sheet.

```
Sub Intialize()
Dim iRow As Long
iRow = Sheets("Timings").Range("H" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'Code to Validate
If Sheets("Timings").Range("F" & iRow).Value = "" Then
    Sheets("Timings").Range("B" & iRow).Value = Format([Today()], "DD-MMM-YYYY")
    Sheets("Timings").Range("C" & iRow).Value = Application.UserName

End If
End Sub

Sub Start_Time()
Dim iRow As Long
iRow = Sheets("Timings").Range("H" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'Code to Validate
If Sheets("Timings").Range("D" & iRow).Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please add Number", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "NO NUMBER"
    Sheets("Timings").Range("D" & iRow).Select
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Sheets("Timings").Range("F" & iRow).Value <> "" Then
    MsgBox "Start Time is aleady captured for the selected Task."
    Exit Sub
Else
    Sheets("Timings").Range("F" & iRow).Value = [Now()]
    Sheets("Timings").Range("F" & iRow).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
End If
End Sub

Sub End_Time()
Dim iRow As Long
iRow = Sheets("Timings").Range("H" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'Code to Validate
If Sheets("Timings").Range("F" & iRow).Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Start Time has not been captured for this task."
    Exit Sub
Else
    Sheets("Timings").Range("G" & iRow).Value = [Now()]
    Sheets("Timings").Range("G" & iRow).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
    Sheets("Timings").Range("H" & iRow).Value = Sheets("Timings").Range("G" & iRow).Value - Sheets("Timings").Range("F" & iRow).Value

    Sheets("Timings").Range("H" & iRow).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
End If
End Sub
```

I've tried adding more sheets with new modules but it breaks everything. I've also tried deleting the sheets name to have it as a blanket workbook VBA but again breaks it.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. What means "Breaks everything". How is your code triggered? If you want the code to work on several sheets, you can't hardcode the sheet name, so maybe pass the sheet as parameter.

Comment: it just stops all my timings from working, so i should remove "sheet" from the code?

Comment: If you remove `Sheets("Timings")` from your code, the code will always work on the current active sheet. Don't know if that is what you want to do. Again: How is your code triggered? What calls the subs and when does this happen?

Comment: my code is triggered when i hit a "start" shape/text box and a line of text has been added into the D column. When i remove  Sheets("Timings") my "Stop" shape/text no longer works and this is also the case if i use the code to create a new module for a different sheet

Comment: How and when do you run `Intialize` or should it rather be `Initialize`? Please add a detailed description of what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: hey, the code is supposed to create a duration time in Row H, using a Start/Stop text button calculated in Row F and G. Row D is where I input the Task name that we are timing using the duration

Answer (score 0):

You've shown us three Subs, but I'm only going to illustrate the changes on a single one, `Initialize`, and you can apply the same principles to the others.

> I have this code to create Timings but i can only use it on one sheet.

As others have mentioned in the comments, you cannot hardcode a sheet name and then use that code for other sheets.

> I've tried adding more sheets with new modules but it breaks everything.

I'm not sure what this means.  I believe you're saying that you're creating new subs for each sheet that you want to use these subs for, but replacing the "Timings" with their respective sheet names.  This solution will solve that problem as well.

> I've also tried deleting the sheets name to have it as a blanket workbook VBA but again breaks it.

If you want your code to work for multiple sheets in the same sub, you might want a `For` loop.  I'm going to ignore this for now, though.

Let's pass the worksheet as a parameter to your sub instead:

```
Sub Intialize2(wkSheet As Worksheet)

    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = wkSheet.Range("H" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    'Code to Validate
    If wkSheet.Range("F" & iRow).Value = "" Then
        wkSheet.Range("B" & iRow).Value = Format([Today()], "DD-MMM-YYYY")
        wkSheet.Range("C" & iRow).Value = Application.UserName

    End If

End Sub
```

Now, you can call the `Initialize` sub and give it whatever worksheet you want.  You can use this code to get the same results as your previous code like so:

```
Initialize(wkSheet:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Timings"))
```

Comment: Yes!!! That wksheet renaming worked, i've tried adding a new sheet in the workbook and it works, just doesnt calculate the duration like the timings sheet so i'll need to look into that.

Comment: @ROBIN30 Glad to hear there is progress!  If this answers your question, please "accept" this answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Make Code Work For Any Worksheet in `ThisWorkbook`

**Start**

```vb
Sub Start_Time()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Start Time"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    If Not IsActiveSheetValid(wb) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim NewRow As Long: NewRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    Dim TaskName As String
    
    With ws.Cells(NewRow, "D")
        TaskName = CStr(.Value)
        If Len(TaskName) = 0 Then
            .Select
            MsgBox "Please enter a task name!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    With ws.Cells(NewRow, "F")
        If Len(CStr(.Value)) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "The start time is aleady captured for task """ _
                & TaskName & """!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
        .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
        .Value = Now
    End With
    ws.Cells(NewRow, "B").Value = Format(Date, "DD-MMM-YYYY")
    ws.Cells(NewRow, "C").Value = Application.UserName
    
End Sub
```

**End**

```vb
Sub End_Time()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "End Time"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    If Not IsActiveSheetValid(wb) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim NewRow As Long: NewRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    Dim TaskName As String
    
    With ws.Cells(NewRow, "D")
        TaskName = CStr(.Value)
        If Len(TaskName) = 0 Then
            .Select
            MsgBox "Please enter a task name!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    With ws.Cells(NewRow, "F")
        If Len(CStr(.Value)) = 0 Then
            .Select
            MsgBox "The start time has not been captured for task """ _
                & TaskName & """!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
        
    With ws.Cells(NewRow, "G")
        .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
        .Value = Now
    End With
    
    With ws.Cells(NewRow, "H")
        .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
        .Value = ws.Cells(NewRow, "G").Value - ws.Cells(NewRow, "F").Value
    End With
    
End Sub
```

**Help**

```vb
Function IsActiveSheetValid(ByVal wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Is ActiveSheet Valid?"

    Dim sh As Object: Set sh = ActiveSheet
    
    If sh Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No visible workbooks open!", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If Not sh.Parent Is wb Then
        MsgBox "Wrong workbook """ & sh.Parent.Name & """ selected!", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If Not TypeOf sh Is Worksheet Then
        MsgBox "Sheet """ & sh.Name & """ is not a worksheet!", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    IsActiveSheetValid = True
    
End Function
```